# What happens with this simple thread lock using atomic bool?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was wondering what can happen with the following code. Let's just say you implement a thread lock with a simple atomic that's locked by one thread, and then has possible multiple other thread running a while loop waiting for the bool to because false again:

```
struct MySimpleThreadLock
{
    constexpr MySimpleThreadLock() : bIsLocked(false) {}
    std::atomic<bool> bIsLocked;

    void lock()
    {
        while (bIsLocked);
        bIsLocked.store(true);
    }
    void unlock()
    {
        bIsLocked.store(false);
    }
};

void func()
{
    static MySimpleThreadLock my_lock;

    my_lock.lock();

    // DO SOMETHING 

    my_lock.unlock();
}
```

Let's say Thread 1 locks (sets the bool to true), then threads 2 and 3 execute the same function, run a while loop continually checking if the bool is true. Thread 1 then sets the bool to false. The two threads spinning then are going to check the bool, see it's false, then set the bool to true again. My question is if two threads are spinning waiting for the bool to change to false, is it possible that both see it as false, leave the while loop and both set the bool to true, then exit the lock function and enter the critical section together?

Comment: `is it possible that both see it as false, leave the while loop and both set the bool to true, then exit the lock function and enter the critical section together?` Yes. Atomic exchange will solve this problem.

Comment: `while (bIsLocked);`?  Probably better using multiple lines as something like `while (bIsLocked) { /* deliberately empty loop */ }`

Comment: Also the while loop will use too much CPU. At least put `yield()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Will not block nothing since every thing can happen between load in while loop and store. For example 2 threads escaped while loop and one sets  `bIsLocked` to `true` and then another sets it to `true` sharing lock with the first one.  Use CAS or basic `atomic_flag`:

```
 std::atomic_flag flag;

    void lock()
    {
        while (flag.test_and_set());
    }
    void unlock()
    {
        flag.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Difference between atomic_flag and atomic< bool >?

Comment: Unlike atomic<bool>,  atomic_flag  always lockfree but with limited interface.